# Multiple conditions (breaks) for cut function

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- as_tibble(c(15:-15))
```

Now i want to add intervals in a new column. The intervals should be like this:

```
df$Intervall <- cut(df$value, seq(from = -15, to = 15, by = 5), include.lowest=TRUE)

   value Intervall
1     15   (10,15]
2     14   (10,15]
3     13   (10,15]
4     12   (10,15]
5     11   (10,15]
6     10    (5,10]
7      9    (5,10]
8      8    (5,10]
9      7    (5,10]
10     6    (5,10]
11     5     (0,5]
12     4     (0,5]
13     3     (0,5]
14     2     (0,5]
15     1     (0,5]
16     0    (-5,0]
17    -1    (-5,0]
18    -2    (-5,0]
19    -3    (-5,0]
20    -4    (-5,0]
21    -5  (-10,-5]
22    -6  (-10,-5]
23    -7  (-10,-5]
24    -8  (-10,-5]
25    -9  (-10,-5]
26   -10 [-15,-10]
27   -11 [-15,-10]
28   -12 [-15,-10]
29   -13 [-15,-10]
30   -14 [-15,-10]
31   -15 [-15,-10]
```

The result has the Problem, that all the zeros (0) in value go to intervall -0:-5 which makes it lose symmetry between positive and negative values. 5 is interval 0,5 but -5 is interval -10:-5.

I want every 0 to be intervall 0 or 0:0, so i have symmetry and -5 is interval 0:-5.

The result should look like this:

```
   value Intervall
1     15   (10,15]
2     14   (10,15]
3     13   (10,15]
4     12   (10,15]
5     11   (10,15]
6     10    (5,10]
7      9    (5,10]
8      8    (5,10]
9      7    (5,10]
10     6    (5,10]
11     5     (0,5]
12     4     (0,5]
13     3     (0,5]
14     2     (0,5]
15     1     (0,5]
16     0    (0,0]
17    -1    (-5,0]
18    -2    (-5,0]
19    -3    (-5,0]
20    -4    (-5,0]
21    -5    (-5,0]
22    -6  (-10,-5]
23    -7  (-10,-5]
24    -8  (-10,-5]
25    -9  (-10,-5]
26   -10  (-10,-5]
27   -11 [-15,-10]
28   -12 [-15,-10]
29   -13 [-15,-10]
30   -14 [-15,-10]
31   -15 [-15,-10]
```

jay.sf solution works for this small sample data frame. It's not practical for my real data frame which is bigger. So i really want to cut and add exceptions instead of doing it by hand. I am not sure, how that is possible though.

Comment: Shouldn't 1:5 be `(1,5]` and `-1:-5` be `(-5,-1]` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `(0,0]` be `[0,0]` and `(1,5]` be either `(0,5]` or `[1,5]`?

Comment: I dont know why sometimes ( is used instead of [. I am just using the functions. I edited the question again. maybe now its clearer

Comment: It is about open and closed intervals/sets: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals

Comment: Maybe using `findInterval` will work in case you are using integer values: `findInterval(15:-15, c(seq(-15,0,5), 1, 1+seq(5,15,5)))` and with `cut` `cut(15:-15, c(seq(-15,0,5), 1, 1+seq(5,15,5)), right = FALSE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabe subtracting and adding 0.5 around 0 could be usable for you.

```
cut(15:-15, c(seq(-15,0,5) - 0.5, 0.5 + seq(0,15,5)))
# [1] (10.5,15.5]   (10.5,15.5]   (10.5,15.5]   (10.5,15.5]   (10.5,15.5]  
# [6] (5.5,10.5]    (5.5,10.5]    (5.5,10.5]    (5.5,10.5]    (5.5,10.5]   
#[11] (0.5,5.5]     (0.5,5.5]     (0.5,5.5]     (0.5,5.5]     (0.5,5.5]    
#[16] (-0.5,0.5]    (-5.5,-0.5]   (-5.5,-0.5]   (-5.5,-0.5]   (-5.5,-0.5]  
#[21] (-5.5,-0.5]   (-10.5,-5.5]  (-10.5,-5.5]  (-10.5,-5.5]  (-10.5,-5.5] 
#[26] (-10.5,-5.5]  (-15.5,-10.5] (-15.5,-10.5] (-15.5,-10.5] (-15.5,-10.5]
#[31] (-15.5,-10.5]
#7 Levels: (-15.5,-10.5] (-10.5,-5.5] (-5.5,-0.5] (-0.5,0.5] ... (10.5,15.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trick and cut at slightly below and above zero, e.g. `-0.1` and `0.1`, and define custom `labels=`.

```
data.frame(x, interval=cut(x, c(-15.1, -10.1, -5.1, -.1, -.1, 5, 10, 15), 
                  labels=c("[-15,-10)", "[-10,-5)", "[-5,-1]", "0", "[1,5]", 
                           "(5,10]", "(10,15]"), include.lowest=T))
#      x  interval
# 1   15   (10,15]
# 2   14   (10,15]
# 3   13   (10,15]
# 4   12   (10,15]
# 5   11   (10,15]
# 6   10    (5,10]
# 7    9    (5,10]
# 8    8    (5,10]
# 9    7    (5,10]
# 10   6    (5,10]
# 11   5     [1,5]
# 12   4     [1,5]
# 13   3     [1,5]
# 14   2     [1,5]
# 15   1     [1,5]
# 16   0         0
# 17  -1   [-5,-1]
# 18  -2   [-5,-1]
# 19  -3   [-5,-1]
# 20  -4   [-5,-1]
# 21  -5   [-5,-1]
# 22  -6  [-10,-5)
# 23  -7  [-10,-5)
# 24  -8  [-10,-5)
# 25  -9  [-10,-5)
# 26 -10  [-10,-5)
# 27 -11 [-15,-10)
# 28 -12 [-15,-10)
# 29 -13 [-15,-10)
# 30 -14 [-15,-10)
# 31 -15 [-15,-10)
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- 15:-15
```

Comment: That is an interesting approach. Two things i have to mention: If you look closely, the intervals are not correct for the negative values. -5 should fall into -1:-5 intervall, not -5:-10, mirrored to the positive values. Second thing is that my data frame can get quite big, so i want to be able do define the extreme values quickly. Kinda like cut(df$value, seq(from = -1000, to = 1000, by = 5), include.lowest=TRUE) but with the two exceptions i mentioned.

Comment: @Dutschke You're right, we need to continue the logic for all negative values. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works for this small example but it will get unhandy with my real data. I will add that information to the question.